# ggplot2: crop legend box

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a heat map with `geom_tile`containing this legend.

[image: red to blue legend going from 5 to -9]

This is the code within `ggplot()` that I used:

```
scale_fill_gradient2(name = "log2(fold change)",
                             low = "navy",
                             mid = "white",
                             midpoint = 0,
                             high = "red",
                             breaks = c(-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4),
                             limits = c(-9,5),
                             guide = guide_colorbar(frame.colour = "black", 
                                                    ticks.colour = "black",
                                                    barheight = 13.5))
```

In my current plot, it creates the legend and shows the colour gradient, ranging from -9 to 5.
My question is how to crop the legend, so that it only shows the values ranging from -4 to 5, **without changing the colour gradient** ([like in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Eu7.png)). How can this be achieved?

Comment: Try `limits = c(-4,5)` instead of a lower limit of -9.

Comment: This would indeed crop the legend, but it also changes the colour gradient, which is what I do not want to do. This reason for this is that I want to have the exact same colour gradient across different heat maps, where the range of the values might differ.

Comment: Maybe it's my eyes but I don't see it change the gradient. When the lower limit is -9 the blue color is much darker than when it is -4.